# Google search for images sometimes messes up?

Tags: search

Every time I search for something on Google's image tab sometimes it just pops up random images. Say I Google 'Harry Potter' and the 60th search item is a picture of 'Macaulay Culkin'. I mean how does that even happen? I know this isn't a strictly coding question but I would like to know why exactly Google's search algorithm fails (if I can say that).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case of a failing algorithm.  It may be that the picture is on a harry potter website, or that the picture is tagged with "Harry Potter."  It's most likely the first senario.

Also, you'll notice that as you scroll farther to the bottom, the results are less like your search. It's supposed to show the most relevant results at the top (unless you changed that order option).

Comment: Still, there are so many other pictures of Harry Potter (and other random things) on other Harry Potter sites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's not google's fault.  Also, you'll notice that as you scroll farther to  the bottom, the results are less like your search.  It's supposed to show the most relevant results at the top  (unless you changed that order option).